# Given $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \text{Unif}(0,d)$ independent random points. Find the probability that the smallest distance is larger than 1.

Tags: calculus, probability

## Exploration

If $n-1 > d$ then there is no way to fit the points such that the minimum distance is greater than 1; so the probability is 0.

From now on we assume $n-1 \leq d$ and we consider $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$, the order statistics, since the joint density function is $n!f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = n!\frac{1}{d^n} \text{ if } x_1,\ldots,x_n \in [0,d]$ (And then integrate over all valid ordered values)

Additionally a simulation will be used to verify if formulas are accurate. ($t=1,000,000$)

### $n=2$

$$\int_0^{d-1}{\int_{x+1}^d{2!\frac{1}{d^2}}dx}dx = \left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^2$$

*Verification for $d=1,2,3,5,7$*

```
 d Formula  Simulation   Error Abs  Error Rel
-- -------- ------------ ---------- ----------
 1 0        0.0                   0         0%
 2 1/4      0.250231       0.000231    0.0924%
 3 4/9      0.444837       0.000392    0.0883%
 5 16/25    0.639972      -0.000028   -0.0043%
 7 36/49    0.735327       0.000633    0.0861%
```

### $n=3$

$$\int_0^{d-2}{\int_{x+1}^{d-1}{\int_{x+1}^d{3!\frac{1}{d^3}}dx}dx}dx = \left(\frac{d-2}{d}\right)^3$$

*Verification for $d=2,3,5,7,11$*

```
 d Formula   Simulation   Error Abs  Error Rel
-- --------- ------------ ---------- ----------
 2 0         0.0                   0         0%
 3 1/27      0.037213       0.000175    0.4751%
 5 27/125    0.216259       0.000259    0.1199%
 7 125/343   0.364595       0.000163    0.0448%
11 729/1331  0.547615      -0.000093   -0.0001%
```

### $n=4$

$$\int_0^{d-3}{\int_{x+1}^{d-2}{\int_{x+1}^{d-1}{\int_{x+1}^d{4!(\frac{1}{d})^4}dx}dx}dx}dx = \left(\frac{d-3}{d}\right)^4$$

*Verification for $d=3,5,7,11,13$*

```
 d Formula     Simulation   Error Abs  Error Rel
-- ----------- ------------ ---------- ----------
 3 0           0.0                   0         0%
 5 16/625      0.025546      -0.000054   -0.2109%
 7 256/2401    0.106747       0.000124    0.1170%
11 4096/14641  0.279910       0.000147    0.0527%
13 10000/28561 0.350191       0.000063    0.0180%
```

### General $n$

Intuitively it looks like the formula will be:

$$\left(\frac{d-n+1}{d}\right)^n$$

Lets try some random $n \in [10,20]$, $d \in [300,400]$ and $t=100,000$

```
 n   d Formula      Simulation   Error Abs  Error Rel
-- --- ------------ ------------ ---------- ----------
15 396 0.582804176  0.58406       0.0012558   0.21547%
17 347 0.448203066  0.45017       0.0019669   0.43884%
11 359 0.732893318  0.73485       0.0019566   0.26698%
15 375 0.565117834  0.56386      -0.0012578  -0.22257%
13 381 0.659656850  0.66042       0.0007631   0.11568%
```

Ok, this might be it. So next step is to prove the formula.

## Proof Attempt

**Proof by Induction**

### Base (n=2)

This was proved in the exploration

### Hypothesis

For k points in a (0,d) segment, the probability that none are closer than 1 is: $\left(\frac{d-k+1}{d}\right)^k$

### Inductive Step

$$\int_0^{d-k} \int_{x+1}^{d-k+1} \ldots \int_{x+1}^{d}{(k+1)!(\frac{1}{d})^{k+1}}dx \ldots dx dx$$

$$=\int_0^{d-k} \frac{k+1}{d} \int_{x+1}^{d-k+1} \ldots \int_{x+1}^{d}{k!(\frac{1}{d})^k}dx \ldots dx dx$$

Using the hipothesis, but for a $(x+1, d) \equiv (0, d-x-1)$ segment of length $d - x - 1$

$$=\int_0^{d-k} \frac{k+1}{d} \frac{(d-x-k)^k}{(d-x-1)^k}  dx$$

And what should be shown is:

$$\frac{(d-k+2)^{k+1}}{d^{k+1}} =\int_0^{d-k} \frac{k+1}{d} \frac{(d-x-k)^k}{(d-x-1)^k}  dx$$

or

$$\frac{(d-k+2)(d-k+2)^{k}}{(k+1)d^{k}} =\int_0^{d-k} \frac{(d-x-k)^k}{(d-x-1)^k}  dx$$

**Magic should happen here!** (Ie, here is where I got stuck)

## Annex

### [simulation.py](https://repl.it/I2tO/0)

```
import numpy

def trial(d, n):
    """Returns the minimum distance given n random points in (0,d)."""
    sample = numpy.random.uniform(0, d, n)
    distances = (abs(x - y)
                 for (i1, x) in enumerate(sample)
                 for (i2, y) in enumerate(sample)
                 if i1 < i2)
    return min(distances)

def run(d, n, t):
    """Returns the ratio of trials which min distance was larger than 1 and t.

    For big enough t it will converge to the probability."""
    trials = (trial(d, n) for x in range(t))
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x >= 1, trials)))/t
```

## Footnotes

- English isn't my first language, please point any mistake or funky terminology.

Comment: That's a nice analysis you made there. Just a note, you can't write $dx\dots dxdx$ in the integral, because we're not integrating for the same variable, but it should be $dx_1 dx_2\dots dx_k$ and the integral limits should be modified accordingly.

Comment: Also, I think you wanted to write $d-k$ instead of $d-k+2$. near the end, as $d-(k+1)+1 = d-k$

Comment: I won't make the corrections in this post since doing so would invalidate your answer.

Comment: How will it invalidate my answer? The answer assumes you made the corrections :)

Comment: Well, with the corrections I would no longer be stuck. (including the ones mentioned in your answer)

So I would rather leave the answer as is.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest (if you have time) to do the corrections from the comments above regarding dxdxdx as that is mostly stylistic and the d-k+2 as that is pretty much a typo. The answer focuses on a more substantial mistake of the wrong pdf used for induction step and will still be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral will have some logarithm in it, so it won't be equal to what you want.

You made a mistake in your reasoning when you identified $(x+1, d)$ and $(0, d-x-1)$.

Namely, $\int_{x_1+1}^{d-k+1} \ldots \int_{x_k+1}^{d}{k!\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^k}dx_{2} \ldots dx_{k+1} \neq \frac{(d-x_1-k)^k}{(d-x_1-1)^k}$, because $\frac1d$ isn't the pdf of a uniform $U[0, d-x_1-1]$ distribution.

If you correct that and write $\frac1d=\frac{d-x_1-1}{d}\frac1{d-x_1-1}$ you get
\begin{align}
&\int_{x_1+1}^{d-k+1} \ldots \int_{x_k+1}^{d}{k!\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^k}dx_{2} \ldots dx_{k+1} \\ =& \left(\frac{d-x_1-1}{d}\right)^k \int_{x_1+1}^{d-k+1} \ldots \int_{x_k+1}^{d}{k!\left(\frac{1}{d-x_1-1}\right)^k}dx_{2} \ldots dx_{k+1}\\ =& \left(\frac{d-x_1-1}{d}\right)^k\frac{(d-x_1-k)^k}{(d-x_1-1)^k}\\
=& \left(\frac{d-x_1-k}{d}\right)^k.
\end{align}

Thus at the end you get (rewriting $x_1$ as $x$):
$$
\int_0^{d-k} \frac{k+1}{d} \frac{(d-x-k)^k}{d^k} dx = \left(\frac{d-k}{d}\right)^{k+1}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks a lot.